# Book recommendation and advice needed.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

My question is regarding which texts to follow for Geometry and Combinatorics for Olympiad Preparation.
I have done Geometry at a high school level and have a fair share of problem solving experience not particularly of Olympiad though. As for Combinatorics I have currently started with Permutation and Combinations.

> I went through all the posts regarding books for Olympiads but I still couldn't find something which suits my level which is the sole reason for asking this question again.

**My Question might sound a bit naive but, I know that olympiad thinking embraces only through practice, my concern is finding something which does so, but in a step-by-step manner.**
For instance, texts like-: *Modern Olympiad Number Theory by Aditya Khurmi*
. Also I would prefer something which doesn't go too advanced and is a bit friendly.

> I sat for the stage 1 Olympiad this year, and apparently, failed miserably with only 2/100; I would appreciate some advice regarding my score or what I can do to improve.

**A book that connects concepts and techniques will suit me the best.**
*Before hand, please do NOT recommend books like Evan Chen or Pranav A Sriram.*